# solving an equation-differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve this - $$ (y^4 -2x^3y)dx + (x^4 - 2xy^3)dy = 0\ $$
Pretty direct--homogeneous equation that can be solved with y=vx

It is also non-exact, with integrating factor $$\frac1{(y^4 -2x^3y)x + (x^4 - 2xy^3)y } $$

1/(Mx + Ny)

I wanted to know if there is a shorter way around the problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart the trivial solutions $y(x)=0$ and $x(y)=0$, then let $y=xt$

$((xt)^4-2x^3(xt))dx+(x^4-2(xt)^3x)*(xdt+tdx)=0$

$(t^4-2t)dx+(1-2t^3)*(xdt+tdx)=0$

$(-t^4-t)dx+(1-2t^3)*xdt=0$

$\frac{1}{x}dx=\frac{1-2t^3}{t^4+t}dt$

and you integrate it.

Comment: I got that. Is there any other way around the problem ?

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it and it applies to almost all homogeneous differential equations. If you integrate the last equation given by JJacquelin, you should arrive to a very simple result.

Comment: I would give the same answer than Claude Leibovici : The integration is easy, so why looking for another method ? By the way, you could let $u=x^3$ and $v=y^3$, which leads to a simpler equation.